# Can I apply CWT on a digital signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, analog, analog-to-digital

First, I am so sorry for my dumb and stupid question, I am very beginner with signals.
Say that I have an **ultrasonic sensor** cabled to an **ADC** (*Analog to Digital Converter*).
The ADC converts the analog values issued from the sensor to numerical/digital values between 0 and 1023 to be read by the Raspberry Pi.
My question is "**Can I apply CWT (*Continuous Wavelet Transform*) on those values that I got from the ADC?** (*since they are the digital form of the analog signal issued from the ultrasonic sensor*)" or shall I only apply CWT on an analog signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can use the CWT on your analog signal.

There is a Matlab example at:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/examples/time-frequency-analysis-with-the-continuous-wavelet-transform.html

You use a digital computer in either case.

You might want to sample at a higher rate if you are looking at signals with short transient components. A general rule of thumb is about 5 X Nyquist rate sampling.